# "Can't send request" Facebook Problem

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-privacy, facebook-friend-request, facebook-friends

When I want to add people outside my country, 9/10 times I get the Pop-Up saying:

"Can't send request

It looks like you may not know this person. Send requests to people who you know personally to see their updates on Facebook."

Why does this happen so often and what can I do regarding the situation?

Much appreciation to anyone that sheds some light.

Comment: Sometimes this error message appears if we try to send a third friend request in a row the same day. But for some people, we are allowed to send the third friend request, I don't know if it is because of their country.